# Buefy/BoostrapVue namespace conflict

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, buefy

I am trying to use buefy's b-table component at the same time using BootrapVue. I'm guess that BootstrapVue has a component named b-table as well which is causing a confict and resulting in buefy's table not working correctly. When I remove BootstrapVue the Buefy table displays correctly. I'm new the vue and I'm not sure how to resolve namespace conflicts like this or if it is even possible.

**main.js**

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';
Vue.use(Buefy)
```

**MetadataTable.js**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- BootstrapVue -->
    <b-modal id="metadata-modal" title="Metadata" size="lg">
      <p class="my-4">
        <table style="text-align:left">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value,key) in current_metadata">
              <td style="vertical-align:top;font-weight:bold;">{{key}}&nbsp</td>
              <td><code><pre>{{JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}}</pre></code></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </p>
    </b-modal>
    <!-- Buefy -->
    <b-table
        :data="data"
        paginated
    >
      <template slot-scope="props">
          <b-table-column field="metadata.title" label="Title" sortable>
              {{ props.row.metadata.title }}
          </b-table-column>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import only specific modules from `BootstrapVue` that needed to your project rather than importing all of the bootstrap-vue components:

```
import bModal from 'bootstrap-vue'
import bAlert from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.component('b-modal', bModal)
Vue.component('b-alert', bAlert)
```

Hope it will fix `b-table` conflict.